# Comparing Datetime / Timestamp Values From Two Databases for Employee Scheduling (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime, join

My goal is to compare a table of employee schedules from one database, to their actual clock in times in another.

Here is the query I'm starting with to simply find a singular clock-in time when searching the clock-in database:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users_log`
WHERE `user` = 'Employee'
AND `type` = 'Login'
ORDER BY ABS(`logintime` - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`scheduled_logintime_from_2nd_database`)))
LIMIT 1
```

Not sure on the best way to do this (specifically because using the ORDER BY in a subquery is iffy).   But ultimately I'd want some sort of parent query / join that would join the two databases on the Employee Name (`user`), and show both the scheduled logintime, and actual logintime from the two databases.

In the above example, for `scheduled_logintime_from_2nd_database` I'm just using a text string for testing, eventually that'd be the actual column from the other database.  (note one is a timestamp, the other a datetime, hence the UNIX_TIMESTAMP function).

Answer (score 1):

You're very close.

I suggest you proceed as follows:

First, do an appropriate JOIN operation to gather your two sources of data together.  Something like this:

```
      SELECT DATE(ul.logintime) day,
             ul.name, ul.logintime,
             UNIX_TIMESTAMP(sch.scheduled_logintime) sched_time
       FROM users_log ul
       JOIN schedule sch  ON ul.name = sch.name
                         AND DATE(ul.logintime) = DATE(sch.scheduled_logintime)
```

This should get you a bunch of rows, one or more for each day and user, showing scheduled and actual times.

Then you can use that as a subquery, perhaps doing something like this:

```
 SELECT name, day,
        MAX(ABS(logintime - sched_time)),
        MIN(ABS(logintime - sched_time))
   FROM ( SELECT DATE(ul.logintime) day,
             ul.name, ul.logintime,
             UNIX_TIMESTAMP(sch.scheduled_logintime) sched_time
       FROM users_log ul
       JOIN schedule sch  ON ul.name = sch.name
                         AND DATE(ul.logintime) = DATE(sch.scheduled_logintime)
        )
  GROUP BY name, day
```

That should give you each name's best and worst adherence to a schedule in each day.